# Convert cell names to variable names to extract data from another dataset in matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, matrix, cell-array

```
% Initial Inputs
 S.P1=[0.1,0.2,0.3]; % Varies in length
 S.P2=[3.5,5.5];
 S.P3=[7,8,9,10];
```

C is 50x3 matrix of integer indices to assign values of P1, P2, P3.

```
for i=1:numel(fieldnames(S))
      x{i}=['S.P',num2str(i)];
end
x={'S.P1','S.P2','S.P3'};  %Output of for loop
```

How to use cell name as variable names to extract the values of P1, P2, P3.

```
[S.P1(C(:,1)),S.P2(C(:,2)),S.P3(C(:,3))] % Desired Output
```

How to use variable names generated in for loop to extract data as shown above.

Comment: replace the assignment inside the loop  so that it will generate only the field name, without the `S.`, then you can call it dynamically. For the full solution, use inside the loop this line instead what you have: `data = [data ,S.(['P',num2str(i)])(C(:,i))];`, while you define `data = [];` before the loop

Comment: Thanks Adiel, Put ans in Answer section.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut way

data=[data,S.(['P',num2str(i)])(C(:,i))]